# snprintf() return value when size=0

Tags: command, printf, size

Thanks first for your time spent here. I have a question with snprintf() when size=0, with code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
   char *str;
   int len;

   len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s %d", *av, ac);
   printf("this string has length %d\n", len);

   if (!(str = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char))))
      return EXIT_FAILURE;

   len = snprintf(str, len + 1, "%s %d", *av, ac);
      printf("%s %d\n", str, len);

   free(str);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

when I run:

```
momo@xue5:~/TestCode$ ./Test_snprintf
```

The result is:

```
this string has length 17
./Test_snprintf 1 17
```

What confuses me is in the code, the size to be written is 0, why displayed 17?

What did I miss？

Thanks~~

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be found [in the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) under `Return value`;

> The functions **snprintf()** and vsnprintf() do not write more than size bytes (including the terminating null byte ('\0')). If the output was truncated due to this limit then the return value is ***the number of characters (excluding the terminating null byte) which would have been written to the final string if enough space had been available.***

This is so that you can do exactly what you do, a "trial print" to get the correct length, then allocate the buffer dynamically to get the whole output when you snprintf again to the allocated buffer.

Comment: @momoxinduo You pass `NULL` in to only get the length so that you can dynamically allocate memory for doing the real print. Exactly what your code is doing.